# HipChat People Menu on Left

Tags: hipchat

This may well be a profoundly stupid question, but in HipChat how do I add people who are already on my team (and accessing rooms in HipChat) to the People menu on the left (below the Rooms list)? I can invite new team members, but I just want to chat directly with one person already using the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a private chat with a member, it will automatically add them on the left hand side(under the

People Group) which is located underneath the **ROOMS** you are a member of already.

Optionally you can hover over an existing member and click the "x' to remove them.

That list of people, on the left hand side, from what i gather is recently contacted users.

hope that helps